# DateUtil.ToUniversalTime() and DateUtil.ToServerTime() return unexpected values in unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, settings

I have a case where the following code returns a different result depending on if I am debugging the site, or running the code in a unit test:

`var start = DateUtil.ToUniversalTime(@event.Start_Date);`

Where `@event.Start_Date` is `12:00PM, December 1, 2030` and the `Kind` of the date is `Unspecified`. This is the case regardless of where the code runs. That is, I have confirmed that the input is always the same.

When I run this code in a unit test, `start` evaluates to `7:00PM`, whereas if I run this code while debugging the site, it's `5:00PM`.

I suspect that this has to do with how the `DateUtil.ToUniversalTime()` works:

```csharp
public static DateTime ToUniversalTime(DateTime serverTime)
{
    if (serverTime.Kind == DateTimeKind.Utc)
    {
        return serverTime;
    }

    if (serverTime == DateTime.MinValue || serverTime == DateTime.MaxValue)
    {
        return serverTime.SpecifyKind(DateTimeKind.Utc);
    }

    if (serverTime.Kind == DateTimeKind.Local)
    {
        return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(serverTime);
    }

    return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(serverTime, Settings.ServerTimeZone);
}
```

That is, if the `Kind` of the passed `DateTime` is `Unspecified`, the method returns the result of:

`TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(serverTime, Settings.ServerTimeZone)`

The key being that it makes a call to `Settings.ServerTimeZone`.

My Sitecore site uses the `Eastern` timezone, whereas my local machine uses `Mountain` timezone, so the delta (2 hours difference) matches up with what I think is going on.

I see two options:

1. Avoid the use of `DateUtil.ToUniversalTime()` and instead use `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(serverTime, Settings.ServerTimeZone)` for this specific case
2. Mock `Settings.ServerTimeZone` as Eastern time in my tests

One revelation that has come out of this for me is that `Sitecore.DateUtil` isn't always going to behave as expected when running unit tests, nor any Sitecore util class that reference config settings under the hood.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Technique for changing Sitecore configuration for unit tests](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3004/technique-for-changing-sitecore-configuration-for-unit-tests)

Comment: So there are several ways to go about mocking changes to settings; the more common ones listed out in the answer I've linked here. That said, unit tests of any kind should not really be concerned with server timezones and time conversion.

Comment: Thanks @MarkCassidy. I have updated the question to highlight how it differs from the question you linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My analysis proved correct. Some Sitecore util functionality will behave differently in unit tests than when debugging the site because the unit tests don't natively inherit the site's Sitecore config settings. Those values must be fed to the unit tests according to the suggestions listed [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3004/technique-for-changing-sitecore-configuration-for-unit-tests).

In this specific case, modifying my `app.config` of the test project resolved the issue to provide the expected server time zone resolved the issue:

```xml
<sitecore>
  <settings>
    <setting name="ServerTimeZone" value="Eastern Standard Time"/>
  </settings>
</sitecore>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need in hardcoding setting value in the config. You can specify it directly in the unit test via `SettingsSwitcher` from the `Sitecore.Configuration` namespace:

```
var date = DateTime.Now.SpecifyKind(DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
Console.Out.WriteLine("Date = {0}", DateUtil.ToUniversalTime(date));
using (new SettingsSwitcher("ServerTimeZone", "Eastern Standard Time"))
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Date = {0}", DateUtil.ToUniversalTime(date));
}
```

Output:

```
Date = 29.06.2023 11:01:09
Date = 29.06.2023 17:01:09
```